# ASP.Net: "Invalid cryptographic message type" error when encrypting message

Tags: asp.net, encryption, cryptography

```
    public byte[] DoEncrypt(string message, X509Certificate2 cryptCert)
    {
        byte[] signedBytes = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(message);
        EnvelopedCms encryptedMessage = new EnvelopedCms(new ContentInfo(signedBytes));

        CmsRecipientCollection recipients = new CmsRecipientCollection();

            CmsRecipient recipient = new CmsRecipient(cryptCert);
            recipients.Add(recipient);


        encryptedMessage.Encrypt(recipient);

        return encryptedMessage.Encode();
    }
```

When my application tries to encrypt a message it throws the exception 'encryptedMessage.RecipientInfos' threw an exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' with the text "Invalid cryptographic message type" occurs in the line "encryptedMessage.Encrypt(recipient)"

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually encrypting signed data (as the variable names suggests), you should not use the default content type for your ContentInfo. Instead you should use the [alternative constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cfes5ff.aspx) that allows you to specify the signedData content type.